# JPA: persist() молча, без исключений не вносит изменения в БД Postgres, но прибавляет счетчик ID

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Не срабатывает запись persist() для тех же объектов, которые нормально читаются, удаляются и обновляются посредством JPA. В базе Postgres есть таблица students:

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    person_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id INTEGER REFERENCES groupz (group_id),
    student_year INTEGER,
    person_name CHARACTER VARYING(30)
);
```

Класс Student наследует ID-поле у родителя Person:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Person {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected int person_id;
    
    public int getId() {
        return person_id;
    }
    ...
```

У Person также есть дочерний класс Professor, он нормально пишется с persist().
Метод из DAO-класса:

```
    public boolean create(Student student) throws DAOException {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            EntityManager em = emf.getFactory().createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(student);
            em.flush();
            em.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new DAOException("Could not create Student", e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Странно, что нет exceptions в логах, консоли и т.п. SQL-запрос отражается в консоли - он валиден, точно такой же запрос в pgAdmin дает нужный результат. При этом, когда я делаю это через pgAdmin, новая запись приходит с намного большим ID - сообразно количеству неудачных попыток сделать запись при помощи JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: Возможно, стоит закрыть транзакцию?

Comment: Хорошо, но `em.close();` - это не оно?

Comment: не уверен, что закрытие em приведет именно к закрытию транзакции. А поведение Postgres очень напоминает именно зарезервированные зависшие ресурсы. В том числе flush должно гарантировать, что данные полностью дошли до СУБД, но вот чтобы они стали доступны - с них должна быть снята блокировка.

Comment: @kami, напишите это в ответ, я поставлю галку. Вы правы, я выделил транзакцию в отдельную переменную `trn`, по результатам вызвал `trn.commit()`, и заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: Будьте добры - напишите ответ сами. Я только начал изучать java и моё предположение основывалось на общих знаниях работы СУБД. В том числе - я ещё не касался hibernate, мой ответ нельзя будет считать полноценным без разъяснений "почему так".

Comment: Это будет несправедливо: на вопрос ответили вы, а писать его буду я, словно я сам догадался. Напишите: "Вы не закрыли транзакцию. Выделите транзакцию в отдельную переменную и закройте ее". Или пусть без ответа висит.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115911/discussion-between-kami-and-danny).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Описанное поведение (ID успешно зарезервированы, но ни одной записи с ними не видно) явно указывает на незавершенные (открытые) транзакции.
Postgres получил данные, выделил под них ресурсы, но держит в заблокированном состоянии до тех пор, пока транзакции не будут закрыты (commit). Теоретически - увидеть данные можно, используя "грязное чтение" (read uncommited), но скорее всего по истечению времени транзакции будут автоматически закрыты и данные пропадут.

Верное решение здесь - в явном виде завершить транзакцию, которая в рамках единственного действия, *по большому счету, и не нужна*. В итоге, должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
    public boolean create(Student student) throws DAOException {
        boolean result = false;
        EntityManager em = emf.getFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trn = em.getTransaction();
        try {
            trn.begin();
            em.persist(student);
            em.flush();
            em.close();
            trn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            trn.rollback();
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new DAOException("Could not create Student", e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```